# C# getting form reference in an eventhandler

Tags: c#, winforms, scope

My problem is not complicated but i've been looking up for quite some time now and can't seem to find the correct way to phrase it so if this is a duplicate I am sorry.

I have a Form created on a button click, within this Form is a table layout which contains a set of Controls (a label, a combo box and a button). What I want to do is to store the current index selected in the combo box when the button is pressed. However, I can't access the combo box when I'm in the button click event handling block.

This is the creation of my Form, nothing extraordinary.

```
        Form settingsWindow = new Form(); 
        settingsWindow.Text = "Connexion settings";
        settingsWindow.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 200);

        TableLayoutPanel layout = new TableLayoutPanel();
        layout.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        Label label = new Label();
        label.Text = "Choose an available COM port";

        Button bt_OK = new Button(); 
        bt_OK.Text = "valider";
        bt_OK.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom;
        bt_OK.Name = "bt_OK";
        bt_OK.Click += Bt_OK_Click;

        ComboBox cb_portList = new ComboBox(); 

        SerialComm serial = new SerialComm();       //Filling the combo box with a list of 
        List<string> portList = new List<string>(); //available  COM ports
        portList  = serial.getAllPorts();
        foreach(string portName in portList)
        {
            cb_portList.Items.Add(portName);
        }

        layout.Controls.Add(label);
        layout.Controls.Add(cb_portList);
        layout.Controls.Add(bt_OK);
```

What I'd like to be able to do is the following, imagine I made a class to store the data I want :

```
private void Bt_OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        datacontainer.selectItem = cb_portList.SelectedItem;
        settingsWindow.close();
    }
```

Am I not able to do so because my Form is already created within an eventhandler ? Or is it just because they're in separate blocks. If so is there a way the new Form and its controls available from outside the block ?

Comment: What about `sender` `Parent` (of course with right casting first)? ... or `bt_OK.Click += (sender, e) => {  /* now you can use settingsWindow */ }` instead method

Comment: Declare the ComboBox instance before the Button, then just `bt_OK.Click += (s, a) => { datacontainer.selectItem = cb_portList.GetItemText(cb_portList.SelectedItem); };`. -- You should probably ask yourself if you really need to setup a Form to select a COM Port from a ComboBox...

Comment: @Jimi thanks for your reply. It's true that using a whole new form for such a thing might be too much, I guess when you start learning, having pop-up windows everytime you press a button sounds like a good idea at first.